# Can we retrieve a file name in run time in jmeter and pass the name in other place

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

During the jmeter run,a log file is created and stored in a location with timestamp. i want to refer the same **filename** in the next postprocessor. how do we achieve it

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the name of the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) in JMeter script?

Something like:

[image]

?

If yes, you can use a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass


def engine = engine = ctx.getEngine()
def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField('test')

test.setAccessible(true)

def testPlanTree = test.get(engine)

SearchByClass<ResultCollector> resultCollectorSearch = new SearchByClass<>(ResultCollector.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(resultCollectorSearch)
ResultCollector resultCollector = resultCollectorSearch.getSearchResults().first()

println('Current .jtl file name: ' + resultCollector.getFilename())
```